# Is there any way to stream music from an RPi2 to an iPhone/iPod/iPad/Other Device from off the network? Like a Plex server, but just for music

Tags: raspbian, server, media-server

I have an 8GB iPhone 5C, and iOS takes up so much storage I only have 5 of that 8 available to me at any given time. I use apps that take up a lot of storage on said device, but I'd like to listen to my music on the way to/from my school. I realise that the Pi 2 is most likely the best way to accomplish such a task.

For this reason, I have researched media server systems, such as *Plex*, *subsonic*, *madsonic* and *Mopidy*, but none fit my criteria. Subsonic and Madsonic require a subscription to use apps. Plex has a 1-minute audio playback restriction on it's apps. Mopidy doesn't have compatibility for apps anyway.

So I am looking for a (preferably small) media/music server, as I am not looking to host videos on the Pi, that will run on Debian ports, specifically the ARM port known as Raspbian. Although Ubuntu is alright, I can package Ubuntu Server 16.04 *Xenial Xerus* for ARM devices.

Thanks for your time, I hope to hear back from you soon!

Yours,

Mirukai

Answer (score 1):

Look into [DLNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) based apps.  There are DLNA clients and servers available for linux and iOS.

- Random page from searching "iOS DLNA" online: http://appadvice.com/appguides/show/dlna-streaming
- Based on a glance through the output from `apt search dlna` on Raspbian, `minidnla` is probably a good place to start; it looks like it is now actually "ReadyMedia" and they have a homepage but it is not very informative; Arch linux wiki documentation is usually very good though and in this case everything from there should apply to usage on any distro: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ReadyMedia

Beware that UPnP may be a distinct feature, so do not get confused by conflating the two.